# How to install same app and run on device as several apps?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a project on android studio and so every time I run my app and choose my device, it overwrites the app and installs my edited code. Is it possible to keep the old app and install the edited code as a new app?

Comment: Use different devices while running.

Comment: I only have one device and i can't use emulators because i don't have intel haxm since i have amd system

Comment: use diff package name every time

Comment: yes change the package name

Comment: The Solution is to take backup of your old project before executing the newone.

Comment: @Rah i forgot about that, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

use different **applicationId** each time in App **build.gradle** file

Answer (score 0):

Change your package name in `AndroidManifest`

```
package="com.xyz.abc"
```

AND

Change Gradle file `applicationId`

```
applicationId 'com.xyz.abc'
```